# Multiple Sidebars in the finder

Tags: finder, sidebar

Is there a way to have multiple sidebars in Finder?

The Finder sidebar is useful for storing shortcuts to different folders. However it becomes lengthy quite quickly.

I want to have a different sidebar for each project I am working on, so each sidebar can contain different shortcuts to different folders.

[Pathfinder](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) does offer this functionality, but I find it a bit klunky to use and the program is quite expensive for just this one feature.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SwitchUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/switchup/) can swap out the Finder preferences and let you manager multiple sets of these preferences, which can give you different sidebars.  Watch the video on their website to get an idea of how it works.